# A strange example of typing in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, typing

it is quite strange that this ocaml snippet is well typed by the toplevel. Look at the structure, if g is of type int->int as shown in the toplevel, the `h x = g x` part of the structure would not be able to get type-unified. So can any one clarify a bit?

```
module Mymodule : sig
  val h:int ->int
  val g: string-> string
end = struct
  let g x = x
  let h x = g x
end
```

This is the topelevel's response:

```
  module Mymodule : sig val h : int -> int val g : string -> string end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The important thing to understand here is that OCaml performs type inference in a compositional manner, i.e., it will first infer type of `struct ... end` and only then it will match the inferred types against `sig ... end` to verify that the structure really does implement the signature.

For example, if you write

```
module Monkey : sig val f : int -> int end =
struct
  let f x = x
end
```

then OCaml will be happy, as it will see that `f` has a polymorphic type `'a -> 'a` which can be specialized to the required type `int -> int`. Because the `sig ... end` makes `Monkey` opaque, i.e., the signature hides the implementation, it will tell you that `f` has type `int -> int`, even though the actual implementation has a polymorphic type.

In your particular case OCaml first infers that `g` has type `'a -> 'a`, and then that the type of `h` is `'a -> 'a` as well. So it concludes that the structure has the type

```
sig val g : 'a -> 'a val h : 'a -> 'a end
```

Next, the signature is matched against the given one. Because a function of type `'a -> 'a` can be specialized to `int -> int` as well as `string -> string` OCaml concludes that all is well. Of course, the whole point of using `sig ... end` is to make the structure opaque (the implementation is hidden), which is why the toplevel does *not* expose the polymorphic type of `g` and `h`.

Here is another example which shows how OCaml works:

```
module Cow =
struct
  let f x = x
  let g x = f [x]
  let a = f "hi"
end

module Bull : sig
  val f : int -> int
  val g : 'b * 'c -> ('b * 'c) list
  val a : string
end = Cow
```

The response is

```
module Cow :
    sig 
      val f : 'a -> 'a
      val g : 'a -> 'a list
      val a : string
    end

module Bull :
    sig
      val f : int -> int
      val g : 'a * 'b -> ('a * 'b) list
      val a : string end
    end
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd say that the `string -> string` typing isn't applied to `g` until it's exported
from the module.  Inside the module (since you don't give it a type) it has the type
`'a -> 'a`.  (Disclaimer: I'm not a module expert, trying to learn though.)